# shrink (img) element height to that of sibling in flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, sizing

I have a flex (direction: row) container with two elements. The first is an image, and the second is a div. Each element takes up 50% of the container's width. My goal is to get the image to always be the same height as its sibling, whose size is determined by its content. The plan is to then use `object-fit: cover` on the image.

I can cause the image to grow to the height of its sibling with `flex: 1`, but I can't cause it to shrink to the height of its sibling if it's the larger of the two. Is it possible to have both?